# lxml - Translate from indirect url to direct url

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am using python and lxml to gather some web data.

If I have some element:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

r = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
file_ = tree.xpath('some_xpath')[0]
url=file_.attrib['href'] #element
```

Which yields something like:

```
../Document1/Document2.aspx?No=123456
```

And my base url is something like:

```
http://www.foo.com/
```

I could just add the base url and clean the indirect leading periods, but there must be a better way.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Python 2 or 3? And congratulations, you're approaching this in a same way which is unusual.

Comment: python 2. please, what would a usual way to approach this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python 2 it's:

```
from urlparse import urljoin
abs = urljoin(base, rel)
```

Comment: So, I would need to know the base? Is there no dynamic way to get this from the parsed object directly?

Comment: This does not work, and yields:
http://www.foo.com/../Document1/Document2.aspx?No=123456

Comment: That's actually correct behavior believe it or not.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept as correct answer. Fwiw: My page specifically had a bug when I passed the leading periods in the url. Once I strippedm those out it worked fine.